# Mutiple database in spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Here is my sessionFactory Configuration.

```xml
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>package</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/msell" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="" />
    <beans:property name="initialSize" value="10" />
    <beans:property name="maxActive" value="5" />
    <beans:property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
    <beans:property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
            transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<beans:bean id="sessionFactorySports"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceSports" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>package</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                    </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="dataSourceSports" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/msell_sports" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="" />
    <beans:property name="initialSize" value="10" />
    <beans:property name="maxActive" value="5" />
    <beans:property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
    <beans:property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="transactionManagerSports"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactorySports" />
</beans:bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
        transaction-manager="transactionManagerSports" />
```

I tried injecting sessionFactorySports like below.

```
@Autowired(required=false)
@Qualifier(value="sessionFactorySports")
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

But Still the original sessionFactory object only gets injected. What's wrong with the configuration ? Why the sessionFactorySports isn't getting injected ?

**EDIT 1:**

I tried changing the first sessionFactory name to sessionFactoryFashion.But now I'm getting "No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: sessionFactoryFashion,sessionFactorySports" this error

Comment: Did you add the <context:annotation-config/> tags somewhere?

Comment: This config is alright. I am able to get the session factory. Please post some code of the how you are accessing session and doing transaction.

Comment: Yeah I tried that also. But now I'm getting "No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: sessionFactoryFashion,sessionFactorySports" this error.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be @Qualifier(“sessionFactorySports″) ??

Heres the reference;
https://softwaredevtips.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/springhibernate-multiple-datasources/

Comment: That also didn't help

Comment: Can you try only with "@Autowired" without "(required=false) ". May be during startup it may indicate some error. Keeping the code as @Qualifier(“sessionFactorySports″)

Comment: Not sure how the entire code of your java file looks like; But most links suggested alternatives. e.g.: autowire by name, configuring in XML, 

Have a look at this link; http://www.techques.com/question/1-5843953/Hibernate-using-multiple-databases

They also suggested problems arise when multiple transaction managers are used.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use multiple datasources the right approach would be to have multiple datasources rather than sessionfactory.

You can achieve this by using or implementing org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.

You can have a look at this

[dynamic-datasource-routing](http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)